# Contextual menu with submenu in flutter web

Tags: flutter, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a contextual menu that replaces the default right-click menu in browsers. Initially, I looked at the different existing packages, such as:

- https://pub.dev/packages/native_context_menu/example
- https://pub.dev/packages/pluto_menu_bar
- https://pub.dev/packages/context_menus

However, each of them has its limitations, so I decided to create my own by following this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ContextMenuController-class.html. The only problem is that I can't create "sub-menus" (see the image).

[image: Context menu example]

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you !